# Create a custom percentile rank for a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate the percentile using a specific algorithm that is not available using either pandas.rank() or numpy.rank().

The ranking algorithm is calculated as follows for a series:

> rank[i] = (# of values in series less than i + # of values equal to
> i*0.5)/total # of values

so if I had the following series

```
s=pd.Series(data=[5,3,8,1,9,4,14,12,6,1,1,4,15])
```

- For the first element, 5 there are 6 values less than 5 and no other values = to 5.  The rank would be (6+0x0.5)/13 or 6/13.
- For the fourth element (1) it would be (0+ 2x0.5)/13 or 1/13.

How could I calculate this without using a loop?  I assume a combination of `s.apply` and/or `s.where()` but can't figure it out and have tried searching. I am looking to apply to the entire series at once, with the result being a series with the percentile ranks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use numpy broadcasting. First convert `s` to a numpy column array. Then use numpy broadcasting to count the number of items less than `i` for each `i`. Then count the number of items equal to `i` for each `i` (note that we need to subract 1 since, `i` is equal to `i` itself). Finally add them and build a Series:

```
tmp = s.to_numpy()
s_col = tmp[:, None]
less_than_i_count = (s_col>tmp).sum(axis=1)
eq_to_i_count = ((s_col==tmp).sum(axis=1) - 1) * 0.5
ranks = pd.Series((less_than_i_count + eq_to_i_count) / len(s), index=s.index)
```

Output:

```
0     0.461538
1     0.230769
2     0.615385
3     0.076923
4     0.692308
5     0.346154
6     0.846154
7     0.769231
8     0.538462
9     0.076923
10    0.076923
11    0.346154
12    0.923077
dtype: float64
```